# Is there any Uglify Express Middleware?

Tags: node.js, express, uglifyjs, uglifyjs2

I'm trying to find an Express Middleware for Uglify, can you recommend one?
It seems like [uglify-js-middleware](https://github.com/JakeWharton/uglify-js-middleware) is trying to solve it to Connect, but it seems like it's not maintained anymore and when I tried it, it didn't with Express.

Comment: Connect middleware should be fully supported in express, as Express is a superset of Connect. What was the problem you experienced when you tried it in Express?

Comment: Have you looked at Grunt? You could uglify, concatenate, and validate JavaScripts files with it. It wouldn't be done on the fly as you are asking, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try these packages :

1. [express-uglify](https://npmjs.org/package/express-uglify)
2. [js-middleware](https://npmjs.org/package/js-middleware)

Comment: js-middleware is 404. Would you mind explaining what these two packages do (or did) so that we can try to find equivalents?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a middleware that I forked based on the less-middleware. I preferred the approach and setup better compared to some of the other options.

[902 Labs - express-uglify-middleware on GitHub](https://github.com/902Labs/express-uglify-middleware)

Answer (score 1):

I think in these days we use

https://github.com/breeswish/express-minify

which does uglify automagically. But beware ... it still does not support ES6